# Can I automate AngularJS login form in Perl using WWW::Mechanize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, perl, web-scraping, www-mechanize

I have a [webpage](https://www.ooredoo.qa/selfcare/#/login/en) that uses AngularJS to show a form with a username field, then a password field and the HTML doesn't have any  or  elements. The next page is a simple HTML form that can be easily automated, two set of  fields and a download button.

I know how to use WWW::Mechanize to automate forms but I'm stuck at the login. I saw some python ways to do this, but I'm not a pythonist, and prefer Perl.

Can WWW:Mechanize do this? any other CPAN modules?

Comment: [Which modules work like Mechanize and have JavaScript support?](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::FAQ#Which-modules-work-like-Mechanize-and-have-JavaScript-support%3f)

Comment: If you post this with more explanation as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: I won't accept similar answers from someone else, I will wait 48 hours before answering it myself

Comment: The point daxim is making is that WWW::Mechanize cannot do that. You're essentially asking for recommendations, which as you probably know is off topic. You need selenium, or WWW::Mechanize::Firefox or ::Chrome and it needs to be run in a windowed environment. The one for Firefox is probably going to stop working at some point. The author's talk about that and the new Chrome one from The Perl Conference in Amsterdam should already be on YouTube. I can't look for it right now. The author is Max Maischain (corion).

Comment: Recently I used Selenium Webdriver with Perl binding and Chrome, and had a very positive experience. Maybe you should try this instead of WWW::Mechanize.

Comment: Edited the question to ask if mechanize can do it or propose alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. Change login and password and paste what you got. You should get tokenId from API, then use this token to authorization.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

my $login = 'lucky';
my $password = 'secretpassword';

$ua->default_header('Accept' => 'application/json, text/plain, */*');
$ua->default_header('Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
$ua->default_header('Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br');
$ua->default_header('Accept-Language' => 'pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7');
$ua->default_header('Connection' => 'keep-alive');
$ua->default_header('Orgin' => 'https://www.ooredoo.qa');
$ua->default_header('Referer' => 'https://www.ooredoo.qa/selfcare/');
$ua->default_header('Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
$ua->default_header('User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36');
my $content = '{"operation":"Login","language":"ENGLISH","parameters":["'.$login.'","'.$password.'"]}';
my $res = $ua->post('https://www.ooredoo.qa/webgate/login', Content => $content );
print $res->decoded_content;
```